# Getting Radio buttons Selection

Tags: c#, radio-button, radiobuttonlist

I have made a program where the user can select a destination by using the radio buttons. My problem is even if the user selects "1" as the destination the program identifies it as "2".

Here is what i have done :

```
public partial class Airplane_Simulation : Form
{
    private String status="";

    public Airplane_Simulation()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CheckedChanged();

        rbOne.CheckedChanged += (s,e) => { CheckedChanged(); };
        rbTwo.CheckedChanged += (s, e) => { CheckedChanged(); };

        //more codes here
    }

    public void CheckedChanged()
    {
        status = rbOne.Checked ? rbOne.Text : rbTwo.Text;
    }
}
```

What seems to be the problem here ? i have used the if condition to check which one is checked but still i only get the option as "2".

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint there, it reports rbOne.Checked as false?

Comment: Are your radiobuttons part of the same group?

Comment: yea they are part of the same group.

Comment: although your code has something redundant but it's still strange, looks like you have other code causing this issue

Answer (score 0):

This may help you If you want to change the `status` everytime when a checkbox is clicked.

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        rbOne.Click += (s, o) => { status = rbOne.Text; };
        rbTwo.Click += (s, o) => { status = rbTwo.Text; };
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

First the single equal sign is an assignment not a check for equality.
You should use two(2) equal signs.

Then I would use the `rbOne.IsChecked` property to see if the control is checked or not.

The `rbOne.Checked` is an event not a property.

Edit:

the above could be used in WPF. Here is what I would od in Windows Forms:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();



        rbOne.Click += new EventHandler(radioButton_Click);
        rbTwo.Click += new EventHandler(radioButton_Click);
    }

    public void radioButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        status = rbOne.Checked ? rbOne.Text : rbTwo.Text;

}
```

I would not use the CheckedChanged event because it will be called twice when you select the other radio button.

Comment: Where is `IsChecked`? Where is the single equal sign?

Comment: `status = rbOne.Checked ? rbOne.Text : rbTwo.Text;` should read `status == rbOne.IsChecked ? rbOne.Text : rbTwo.Text;`

Comment: That's an `assignment` not a `logical comparison`.

Comment: OK. Should it not read `status = rbOne.IsChecked ? rbOne.Text : rbTwo.Text;` ?

Comment: I'm so sorry! I overlooked the fact that you were using Form.